# Python3 recursive, for-loop, function returns strange output

Tags: python-3.x, list, recursion, return

My function `combinations(ary, p)` is suposed to `return` every possible ***combination***, of order of items in list.
But it always returns the first value multiple times, even tho it finds all the possible orders, which I know because it prints them.

EDIT: I would like to make it work my self, learn something and not use any external libs.

```
def combinations(ary, p):
    ln = len(ary)
    bary=[]
    for a in range(ln-p):
        if p<ln-2:
            bb = combinations(ary, p+1)
            for be in bb:
                bary.append(be)
        if p>=ln-2:
            bary.append(ary)
        ary.append(ary.pop(p))
    return bary
```

Another version with debug print() functions. I will give its sample output.

```
def combinations(ary, p):
    ln = len(ary)
    bary=[]
    for a in range(ln-p):
        if p<ln-2:
            bb = combinations(ary, p+1)
            for be in bb:
                bary.append(be)
        if p>=ln-2:

    -->     bary.append(ary)
    -->     print('ary', ary, 'bary', bary)

        ary.append(ary.pop(p))
    return bary
```

Console output after running with `combinations([7,3,2], 0):`:

```
##  There is clearly every possible combination:
##
##      ||
##      ||
        \/
ary [7, 3, 2] bary [[7, 3, 2]]
ary [7, 2, 3] bary [[7, 2, 3], [7, 2, 3]]
ary [3, 2, 7] bary [[3, 2, 7]]
ary [3, 7, 2] bary [[3, 7, 2], [3, 7, 2]]
ary [2, 7, 3] bary [[2, 7, 3]]
ary [2, 3, 7] bary [[2, 3, 7], [2, 3, 7]]
[[7, 3, 2], [7, 3, 2], [7, 3, 2], [7, 3, 2], [7, 3, 2], [7, 3, 2]]
```

The last list is suposed to include every possible order, but it has only the input value order even tho it prints every order. So where did I mess up the `return`?

Comment: why not just use itertools here `print(list(itertools.permutations([7,3,2])))`

Comment: If I won't be able to fix it I will eventualy have to, but I won't learn anything and I would prefer to make it as  much myself as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is there is only one copy of ary. You append it to bary many times. So bary is full of the same one list. Any time you make a change to ary. That will be reflected in all of them cause they are all the same list.

Instead when you append to bary assign a copy of ary but as a new list of its own so it wont be affected when you change ary

```py
def combinations(ary, p):
    ln = len(ary)
    bary=[]
    for a in range(ln-p):
        if p<ln-2:
            bb = combinations(ary, p+1)
            for be in bb:
                bary.append(be)
        if p>=ln-2:
            bary.append(ary[:]) #Changed this line to take a shallow copy of ary
            print('ary', ary, 'bary', bary)

        ary.append(ary.pop(p))
    return bary

print(combinations([7,3,2], 0))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ary [7, 3, 2] bary [[7, 3, 2]]
ary [7, 2, 3] bary [[7, 3, 2], [7, 2, 3]]
ary [3, 2, 7] bary [[3, 2, 7]]
ary [3, 7, 2] bary [[3, 2, 7], [3, 7, 2]]
ary [2, 7, 3] bary [[2, 7, 3]]
ary [2, 3, 7] bary [[2, 7, 3], [2, 3, 7]]
[[7, 3, 2], [7, 2, 3], [3, 2, 7], [3, 7, 2], [2, 7, 3], [2, 3, 7]]
```

Comment: Maybe add that `bary` is full of *references* to `ary`?

Comment: Huge thanks, I would have never thought that this is what was happening. I woud have gave you upvote but I have not enough points.